# How to redirect to correct URL without knowing input URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Basically how stack overflow does it.

So if the old URL is : `/product-old-url_152` and then it changes to `/product-new-url_152`, then the following URLs would all redirect here:

`/product-old-url_152`

`/product-some-other-url_152`

would both redirect to:

`/product-new-url_152`

What's the best way of doing this?

**EDIT**: `152` is the ID of the post in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this:

Extract the id from the requested URL

```
if (preg_match('/product-(.*)_(\d+)$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches)) {
    $old = $matches[1];
    $id = $matches[2];
```

lookup the new URL in the database

```
    $slug = fetch_slug_from_database($id);
```

and send a redirect to the client, if the URL changed

```
    if ($slug !== $old) {
        header("Location: /product-$slug-$id");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: And remember to add a check that you're not already on the new URL, or you'll get stuck in a loop.

Comment: @iainn Thanks for spotting, fixed.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Thanks for this. Will definitely look at implementing.